# popToViewRootController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a messenger app, and I currently have three views: views A (root view), B, and C.

View A is the overview of the messages - the people I'm currently talking to. Upon clicking on a person's text, I will be brought to view C, where I can talk and chat to the person.

View B comes after I click "Compose" in View A. It shows all the people I can talk to in the database. Once I click a person's username, I am brought to View C - again, the text message itself.

I want to be able to click "Back" (these are navigation controllers) from View C back to the root view A. Right now, View C's "Back" brings me back to View B, and View B's "Back" brings me to View A.

I have the following code in View C:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)   
}
```

This works, but when clicking View C's "Back", it briefly shows View B, and then goes back to View A. Is there a way to not being able to see View B at all? Or is there another better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What might make more sense is to present View B modally on View A (since it is meant to be temporary). Upon dismissal of View B, you can present View C by pushing it on View A's navigation controller.

This is what the Messages app does.

In order to get a nice transition, you should push View C onto View A without a transition, and make View B fade out when dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: This will take you from A <- C or Two VC's back.

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as! [UIViewController]

self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 3], animated: true)
```

Comment: It crashed unfortunately. Was I supposed to put this in viewWillDisappear()?

Comment: Try using viewControllers.first instead. Count - 3 is out of the bounds of the array.